# Select and join the same table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have stuck somewhere in the select query in CodeIgniter. I want to perform a select query with several joins but the problem is how to join the same table.

Some of My Tables

Users

```
id first_name middle_name last_name gender etc.

1     John        G         Doe        M

2     Marry       H         Moe        F
```

Students

```
student_id, class, transport, parent etc

1             2       4        2
```

My probem is how to show parent name in my select istead of the parent id 2?

My query is this

```
 $sql="SELECT users.id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, 
                         email, gender, avatar, address, contact, class_name, stream_name, 
                         dormitory_name, route_name, roll_num
                         FROM users, meta_data, role_assignment, students, class, stream,
                         dormitory, transport
                         WHERE users.id=meta_data.user_id 
                         AND users.id=role_assignment.user_id  
                         AND role_assignment.role='3'
                         AND users.id=students.student_id
                         AND students.class=class.class_id
                         AND students.stream=stream.stream_id
                         AND students.dormitory= dormitory.dormitory_id
                         AND students.transport=transport.transport_id";
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: To join two table, you have to use an alias.

Comment: Thanks; Can you show me how please @tereško

Comment: `SELECT .. FROM Thing AS First LEFT JOIN Thing AS Second ON First.id = Second.id`

Comment: Thanks; @tereško; but can you guide me by using my query; sorry I didt catch you welll

Comment: No, you will have put in your own effort.

Comment: Hello; I have tried but sill stuck. @tereško

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way in 1992. JOIN us.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry can you now help me to know the appropriate way please; I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT U.first_name, U.last_name, U.middle_name FROM users AS U LEFT JOIN Students AS S ON U.id=S.class
```

It will helps you to solve the problem